# failed to start show plymouth-reboot

Tags: linux, centos7

Job for plymouth-reboot.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status plymouth-reboot.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: And what did those tools tell you?

Comment: systemctl status plymouth-reboot.service
● plymouth-reboot.service - Show Plymouth Reboot Screen
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-reboot.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-05-05 01:06:13 EDT; 12min ago
  Process: 1867 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/plymouthd --mode=shutdown --attach-to-session (code=exited, status=127)

Comment: when i boot my virtual machine, it prompt "failed to start show plymouth boot screen",